# Android offline app that shows free WiFi hotspots

Tags: gratis, android, offline, maps, wifi

I often travel to random countries where roaming is too expensive.

I am looking for an app that:

- Shows a map of nearby free WiFis. Presumably from a community-maintained database, downloaded in advance on the SD card by the app.
- Work 100% offline. Maps can show just my position and the position of the hotspots. Re-using maps from OsmAnd would be wonderful.
- Free, Open Source preferred.
- Runs on Android.

Bonus for:

- Option to switch automatically to free WiFi whenever I am at a hotspot.
- Ability to contribute new hotspots back to the database.

Comment: I recommend you taking a look at my list for [WLAN Finder & Hotspots](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_finder) and, more specifically, the [WeFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wefi.wefi) app. Long time ago that I last used this, so I'm not sure how far its offline-mode currently goes. Let me know if that fits your needs, and I'll make it an answer, though :)

Comment: @Izzy: By the way, are you aware that your site makes Firefox say "android.izzysoft.de uses an invalid security certificate."?

Comment: Ouch, again forgot to replace the "https" by "http" – yes, I'm aware of that. Firefox considers self-signed certificates as "invalid". But as I already put so much of my time into that site, I'm unwilling to buy a certificate and have to replace it every now and then – so I use a self-signed one valid for multiple years. If someone wants to sponsor me a wild-card cert for the second-level domain, valid for 4+ years, I'm accepting that and fix the hole :)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul What about http://maps.me/en/home

Comment: @unique_id: Could you please add an answer detailing how exactly it helps find WiFi? With screenshots showing a map of WiFi hotspots. I could not find anything like this at your link. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't have my phone in my hand  you must read its [features](http://maps.me/en/features)

Comment: @unique_id: Your new link does not mention WiFi either. Even the full user guide does not contain the word "WiFi": http://maps.me/files/MAPS.ME%20User%20Guide%203.0.pdf